# How to organize a correct output of parallel program?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, cout

I have alike C++ program with openMP usage

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for (j=0;j<NUM_STEPS_J) {

    for (i=0;i<NUM_STEPS_I;i++) {

        std::cout << "Print some information about step i" << std::endl;


    }

    std::cout << "Check of item " << j << " finished" << std::endl;
}
```

What is the best way to provide a correct output in my case?

I know, that using "printf" instead "cout" solves this problem.

But when I changed "cout" to "printf" the time of my program's execution increased from about 80 seconds to about 120 seconds. 
I think, it is a sufficient influence on program's productivity.

What is the best way to solve this problem without "printf"?

Is it possible to lock "cout" function during output in some way?

Comment: you could consider to gather some information during runtime and store it in some form of data structure. Then after the run you print a report. This way you would not mix your calculation with printint output. Of course you dont get updates "live".

Comment: Yes, of course it is the most effective way. But the main idea - is to print this information during runtime. In other case information "std::cout << "Check of item " << j << " finished" << std::endl;" is meaningless and I can just remove it and use "#pragma omp critical" for "std::cout << "Print some information about step i" << std::endl;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised to see `printf` being slower than iostreams... (and more so considering that you are using `std::endl` that forces flushing of the buffer) but at any rate, you can use a `stringstream` to construct the output at once and then call either `printf` or `std::cout <<` once with the already built line.

Comment: If I understood correctly, using std::cout in such way "std::cout << String <<std::endl " will never cause wrong output during parallel output?

Comment: @LuckyMan: Yes, but I would append `'\n'` to `String`, and change `std::endl` into `std::flush` (if you really want flushing). This way the race condition on the sequential calls to the two `operator<<` would not affect the output. By using `std::endl;` you are binding the newline to the second call, and another thread writting in the middle would write to the same line (followed by the two newlines), which you probably want to avoid.